# Why was my good explained (IMO) answer downvoted, as well as all other answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer, downvote-reason

I today answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556653/problems-with-elif-and-else-statements), along with some other people - most of the other answers work too, but they do not contain any explanation why the OP is getting this behaviour. Mine does. It was downvoted.

I thought, maybe I did something wrong, but could not find any way to improve my answer. And as all other answers to that question were downvoted too (I did not do that!), I thought, maybe did someone intentionally downvote the question and all answers for some reason? Is there any way to find that out? And, will these downvotes be reversed by the automatic vote reversion system?

Comment: Voting is anonymous so we can't tell why someone voted. Some people are know to downvote duplicates to indicate to answerers that they should be flagging/closing as a duplicate rather than answering, perhaps that's this case but really it's anyone's guess. The votes won't be reversed because they are not serial votes against a single individual.

Comment: I think it's important to understand that even the highest quality of answers are nothing if the question is complete garbage. If the question had been good that's another discussion.

Comment: The fact the question got 5 answers so quickly is also a high indicator that it's a normally a duplicate with a little bit of searching. It might not be the question the OP *asked*, but a different one with the same answer. If the question is worded well, then that doesn't mean the question will be deleted though; a duplicate can still remain after it's closed if its well received and upvoted, and will lead future users with the same question as the OP to the duplicate with the answer (so everyone wins).

Comment: To be fair, it is [often non-trivial to find the canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239036/file-writing-script-just-creates-empty-file-named-0#comment119407645_67239036) and the system is dissonantly designed (optimised/gamified for [quick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731) [non-comprehensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172) answers to *new* questions and not for the stated goal of a (high-quality) knowledge base).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You and others answered a question  for a common problem that already has a good canonical. We don't need more answers to the same question scattered around several Q/A's. We're not Yahoo Answers.

Instead you should have used your close vote privilege and closed the question as a duplicate.

Questions that are duplicates are likely to be downvoted for lack of research. Answers on such duplicates are downvoted for not being useful. If you have an awesome answer to a beaten to death problem, move your answer to the duplicate target.

The downvotes will not be reversed as those votes are legit. For obvious reason I'll not reveal publicly if I downvoted those answers.

Please be more careful going forward with which questions you answer and which questions you vote to close.

Comment: somehow, we must get point to get further on this side, so most answers will be duplicates, i one way or another, no need to downvote the answers as well. super high ranks do it all the time aqnd get upvoted for it.

Comment: @nbk if you're so opposed to it, then stop doing it.

Comment: i don't care , if i get downvoted, but i stoll wanted to get things straight, so that the people know, that the truth is far frpm your post

Comment: "get further on this side", those virtual point only give access to moderation tool. Moderation tool are the kind of thing you don't give to people that are spamming answers on dupe.